# How do I save the date formatting on a CSV file please

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

Hi I have several date fields created in an Excel file with the formatting of yyyy-dd-mm and yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm.  I need to save as a CSV file but lose the formatting when re-opening the file.  Any suggestions please to overcome this please.
Thanks

Comment: If you want to retrieve data from a CSV in a certain format (in your case your date), you'll need to import it versus just opening the file. You can start with Data -> Get & Transform Data -> From Text/CSV. This is basically a power query transformation.

Comment: Can you add another column, interpreting those string fields as Excel date-time? Then when saved in CSV, perhaps Excel can store them in a format easily brought back.

Comment: CSV has no context of an Excel date, which is what Excel, is using to display the time in a specific format.  So you will have to write the date as a string to another column.

Comment: CSV is just values seperated by commas. you are lucky excel trys at all to treat it as a date instead of raw text.

Comment: The date and time in the CSV file should be saved as text in the system format. They will be read in the same format. Therefore, you need to change the format of these cells after loading CSV into Excel, or change the system format to the one you want in the spreadsheet.

Comment: CSV does not contain any formatting information. The data will be saved as displayed (formatted) in Excel, but when you **Open** the file in Excel, it will see what looks like a date, convert it to a date, and display it according to your Windows Regional Settings. If you want to **display** it the same as was formatted, you must **import** the file and designate that column as **Text**.  Of course, then it won't be a "real" date. *If you examine the file with a text editor, you will see how that value is actually saved*